# React native date time picker second click rise an error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm using @react-native-community/datetimepicker and it works perfectly fine if I click on it only once. If I click on it twice it gives me the following error:

> 'value' prop must be an instance of Date object

```
const onChange = (event, selectedHour) => {

        const currentHour = selectedHour || hour;
        setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
        setHour(currentHour.getMinutes())
        let time = parseInt(currentHour.getHours()) + '.' + parseInt(currentHour.getMinutes())
        
        setFinish(parseFloat(time))

  
    };
```

Comment: Hi, datepicker is not getting its value as a Date, this is the reason you are getting this error

Comment: Needs to be a Date object i.e. new Date(...)

Comment: Thank you guys I add this : setHour(new Date(currentHour.getTime()))

Comment: @RohitKhairnar Now whenever I added time finish get the current time not the selected one

Comment: whatever time/date you are getting from datepicker, you have to provide it back to the "value" prop of datepicker in the form of Date object